# android 4.4 ionic hardware button back close keyboard

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I used ionic framework and build a app in android 4.4. 
when I put a input field on some view, and make focus in it, the keybord is showing,but when I press the hardware back button, I want it to hide the keyboard,but it close the current view and go back history view, how can I let it to hide keyboard and don`t to close the current view page? If the focus not in the input field,then press back button let it to close current view is normal.

```
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            // StatusBar.styleDefault();
            StatusBar.styleBlackOpaque();
        }
    });
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
       console.log("aaaaaa:"+$cordovaKeyboard.isVisible());
       function showConfirm() {
           var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
               title: '<strong>exit?</strong>',
               template: 'exit?',
               okText: 'exit',
               cancelText: 'cancel'
           });
           confirmPopup.then(function (res) {
               if (res) {
                   ionic.Platform.exitApp();
               } else {

               }
           });
       }

       if ($location.path() == '/app/home') {
           showConfirm();
       } else
       if ($ionicHistory.backView()) {

            if($cordovaKeyboard.isVisible()) {
                  $cordovaKeyboard.close();
            } else {
                $ionicHistory.goBack();
            }
       } else {
           showConfirm();
        }
        return false;
    }, 101);
```

$cordovaKeyboard.isVisible() is alway return false in $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok，I find a solution about that question.

```
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', keyboardHideHandler);
        function keyboardHideHandler(e){
          var test=$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (e) {
          },1000);
            $timeout(function() {
              test();
            }, 100);
        }
```

I know this method is not best practice, but it can work. If someone find more better method or this method production some bugs, please let me know.